# Estructura de un cubo de rubik

Tags: vb.net, vb

Estoy tratando de hacer un cubo de rubik en vb y por algun motivo, en la clase Rubik, cada vez que añado una cara nueva todas las anteriores se hacen del mismo color.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim rkCube As New Rubik
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        rkCube.start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim x As Integer,
            y As Integer
        For l = 1 To 3
            For c = 1 To 3
                x = c * 50 - 50 + 1
                y = l * 50 - 50 + 1
                rubikBox.CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(rkCube.cube(0)(0)(0)), x, y, 49, 49)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Rubik
    Public _color As Color,
        line As New List(Of Color),
        face As New List(Of List(Of Color)),
        cube As New List(Of List(Of List(Of Color)))

    Function start()
        For f = 1 To 6 'faces
            face.Clear()
            For l = 1 To 3 'lines
                Select Case f
                    Case 1
                        _color = Color.Red
                    Case 2
                        _color = Color.Blue
                    Case 3
                        _color = Color.Orange
                    Case 4
                        _color = Color.Green
                    Case 5
                        _color = Color.White
                    Case 6
                        _color = Color.Yellow
                End Select
                line.Clear()
                For c = 1 To 3 'color
                    line.Add(_color)
                Next
                face.Add(line)
            Next
            cube.Add(face)
        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: sin mas informacion sobre que hace tu codigo y como lo hace, creo que va a ser dificil ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que, en todas tus iteraciones, siempre trabajas con la misma instancia de `line` y `face`.

Lo que no pareces entender es que cuando haces:

```
face.Add(line)
```

... no le estás agregando una copia de `line` a la lista `face`. En realidad le estás agregando *una referencia* a la instancia `face`. De modo que cuando luego, en la siguiente iteración, haces:

```
line.Clear()
```

... esto no solamente borra el contenido de `line`, sino que borra el contenido de lo que le acabas de agregar a `face`, porque en realidad, ambos hacen referencia al mismo contenido/objeto.  Y luego cuando le sigues agregando a la lista con:

```
face.Add(line)
```

... nuevamente, no son copias lo que agregas. De modo que al final, la lista se llena de referencias a la misma instancia `line`.

Y el mismo problema lo tienes en la forma como agregas la instancia `face` a la lista `cube`. Siempre le agregas una referencia a la misma instancia `face`.

Por eso, al final, todas tus caras se ven igual, porque en realidad nunca creastes varias caras. Simplemente modificastes la misma cara varias veces, y lo que ves es tu última modificación.

La solución es que, a cada iteración, en vez de solamente hacer `objeto.Clear()`, que realmente crees una nueva instancia con el keyword `New`.

De te dejo un ejemplo, donde también reduzco tu uso de variables globales. Hay más mejoras que puedes hacer, pero es solo para que puedas ver el punto, que debes crear nuevas instancias a cada iteración:

```
Public Class Rubik
   Public cube As New List(Of List(Of List(Of Color)))

   Sub start()
      For f = 1 To 6 'faces
         Dim face As New List(Of List(Of Color))    ' Crear nueva instancia
         For l = 1 To 3 'lines
            Dim _color As Color
            Select Case f
               Case 1
                  _color = Color.Red
               Case 2
                  _color = Color.Blue
               Case 3
                  _color = Color.Orange
               Case 4
                  _color = Color.Green
               Case 5
                  _color = Color.White
               Case 6
                  _color = Color.Yellow
            End Select
            Dim line As New List(Of Color)         ' Crear nueva instancia
            For c = 1 To 3 'color
               line.Add(_color)
            Next
            face.Add(line)
         Next
         cube.Add(face)
      Next
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: muchas gracias, juro que pensaba que eran diferentes lines

Comment: vale, sigo con un fallo, rkCube.cube(0)(0)(0) = rkCube.cube(5)(0)(0) transforma toda la linea de color y no solo la casilla